# Text will not move to the left in a spinner

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm trying to acheve the text in the spinner to be as far left as I can get it. I've tried several options in the properties box for the spinner with no luck in moving the text to the left. The spinner I'm having issues with is spinner5. Thanks for the help.

**This is what I'm using for the Activity_Main.xml**

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner5"
            android:layout_width="135dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="235dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="235dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-36dp"
            android:background="#c3c3c3"
            android:paddingTop="6dp" />
```

**This is what I'm using for the MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Spinner sp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>ar=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.minesite, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>ar1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.AreaOfInspection,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1); 
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar1);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>ar2=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Personoberving,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar2);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>ar3=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.task,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar3);

        sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner5);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>ar4=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.day,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
        ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        sp.setAdapter(ar4);
```

**Please see the attached picture**

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: have you tried my answer

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do something like this @dweidler.
You have to use a custom layout.

**Create spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="left"
    />
```

**and Initialize your ArrayAdapter Like this in your MainActivity.java**

```
// Initializing an ArrayAdapter
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,R.layout.spinner_item,R.array.your_array);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```